# A web component with ECMA6

Tags: javascript, web-component, ecmascript-6, traceur

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
        <script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
            traceur.options.experimental = true;
        </script>
        <link rel="import" href="x-item.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <x-item></x-item>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my web component:
**x-item.html**

```html
<template id="itemtemplate">
    <span>test</span>
</template>

<script type="module">
    class Item extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            let owner = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
            let template = owner.querySelector("#itemtemplate");
            let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
            let root = this.createShadowRoot();
            root.appendChild(clone);
        }
    }
    Item.prototype.createdCallback = Item.prototype.constructor;
    Item = document.registerElement('x-item', Item);
</script>
```

and I get no error nor what I expect to be displayed, any idea if this should actually work?

Is this how one would extend an HTMLElement in ECMA6 syntax?

**E**: putting it altogether in one page solves the problem at least now I know its the right way to create a custom component, but the problem is having it in a separate file I think it has to do with how traceur handles `<link rel="import" href="x-item.html">` I tried adding the type attribute to the import with no luck.

Comment: And what you expect to be displayed is... what? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: "any idea if this should actually work?" I don't think we can know until we have a conforming implementation of both specifications.

Comment: I'm not convinced you're going to have much luck trying to extend `HTMLElement`.

Comment: @torazaburo its actually possible i can do it with ecma5 so it should be possible with ecma6 unless i am missing something, i am not aware of anything unsupported by traceur in the above syntax and the problem is no error at all just nothing

Comment: What do you see when you examine the DOM?

Comment: (assumption) I doubt traceur isn't able to handle it. After all, it's an ES6 to ES5 compiler, still in development. On the other hand **Web Components** ars a set of developing specs, also under consideration. The combination could be seen as an edge case IMHO, lots of uncertainty. However, are you restricted to write it in that way, or is it just an experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceur's inline processor does not appear to have support for finding `<script>` tags inside `<link import>`. All of traceur's code seems to access `document` directly, which results in traceur only looking at index.html and never seeing any `<scripts>` inside x-item.html. Here's a work around that works on Chrome. Change x-item.html to be:

```
<template id="itemtemplate">
    <span>test</span>
</template>

<script type="module">
(function() {
    let owner = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

    class Item extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            // At the point where the constructor is executed, the code
            // is not inside a <script> tag, which results in currentScript
            // being undefined. Define owner above at compile time.
            //let owner = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
            let template = owner.querySelector("#itemtemplate");
            let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
            let root = this.createShadowRoot();
            root.appendChild(clone);
        }
    }
    Item.prototype.createdCallback = Item.prototype.constructor;
    Item = document.registerElement('x-item', Item);
})();
</script>

<script>
// Boilerplate to get traceur to compile the ECMA6 scripts in this include.
// May be a better way to do this. Code based on:
//   new traceur.WebPageTranscoder().selectAndProcessScripts
// We can't use that method as it accesses 'document' which gives the parent
// document, not this include document.
(function processInclude() {
    var doc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument,
        transcoder = new traceur.WebPageTranscoder(doc.URL),
        selector = 'script[type="module"],script[type="text/traceur"]',
        scripts = doc.querySelectorAll(selector);

    if (scripts.length) {
        transcoder.addFilesFromScriptElements(scripts, function() {
            console.log("done processing");
        });
    }
})();
</script>
```

Another possible solution would be to pre-compile the ECMA6 into ECMA5 and include the ECMA5 only. This would avoid the problem of traceur not finding the `<script>` tags in the import and would remove the need for the boilerplate.